# Save has_and_belongs_to_many link in basic RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I try to learn the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between my 2 fresh new and simple models Product and Author, where a Product can have many authors and where author can have a lots of products.

I wrote this :

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

In the partial form of view for the products, I have :

```
<p>Products</p>
<%= collection_select(:product, :author_ids, @authors, :id, :name, :prompt => " ",  :multiple => true) %>
```

but when I hit the update button, I get this strange message I can't resolve myself :

NoMethodError in ProductsController#update
undefined method `reject' for "1":String

Rails.root: /home/stephane/www/HABTM
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:63:in `block in update'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:62:in`update'
Request

Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2GlTssOFjTVZ9BikrIFgx22cdTOIJuAB70liYhhLf+4=",
 "product"=>{"title"=>"Le trÃ©sor des Templiers",
 "original_title"=>"",
 "number"=>"1",
 "added_by"=>"",
 "author_ids"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update Product",
 "id"=>"1"}

What's wrong ? Is there a problem with :product_ids... I saw on internet I had to pu a "s" but I'm not sure of what it represents....

How can I link the table authors_products to the key which is given back by the drop-down menu ? (here "author_ids"=>"1")
Thx !

More info :
May be solved with this info, but still no saving of the relationship :

```
collection_select("sales_agent", "customer_id", @customers, "id", "name")
```

Assuming you had a customer model with an ID attribute and a name attribute, this would produce exactly the above code. So looking at the values we pass into the collection_select call:

- The first parameter is the model that contains one element from the collection (eg. sales_agent)
- Next is the field name in the model that refers to the collection element it contains (eg. customer_id)
- Next is the variable containing the collection of items that we want to list (eg. @customers)
- Next is the value attribute of the option tag (eg. the customer id)
- Next is the display attribute of the option tag (eg. the customer name)

So I now wrote

```
<p>Products</p>
<%= collection_select(:author, :author_id, @authors, :id, :name, :prompt => " ",  :multiple => true) %>
```

and it worked, but without saving the link, for the moment... (only the update of the normal fields are saved, not the relationship :-(

Comment: please post `app/controllers/products_controller.rb` code in `update` action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a separate model called `author_products` for the HABTM relationship?

You'll need to run another migration by doing something like `rails g model author_product` and the table should only contain two fields:

```
belongs_to :author
belongs_to :product
```

Make sure there is no primary key.

Something like:

```
  def self.up
    create_table(:author_products), :id => false do |t|
       t.references :author
       t.references :product
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, I did this migration and I have the table, with no :id. I only wrote t.integer in place of t.references. Is that a source of problem ?

Comment: No it will be fine as long as the columns are named author_id and product_id. They must also be in alphabetical order I believe. So author must come before product.